# How to add Console window to GUI Application without WinAPI?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I want to use a console window in my gui application. It would be used seldom: open, display some data and then close. Now I am using Win API functions AllocConsole and FreeConsole but I seek a managed way to do It from .NET. Is there any solution for It?

Comment: There is no .NET class wrapper for these functions.  Write your own, pinvoke required.  Or just use a Form with a TextBox or Label.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) you can use Process.Start(); to start a Process and Process.Startinfo.Argument to set input argument's ,and you can also with [StreamOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) or with [StreamError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) get Console Application output .

Comment: You can even redirect the output and show it with a standard WinForms control.

Comment: How exactly Process.Start can replace AllocConsole? O_o

Comment: This is the opposite of what he wants.  You described how to have data from a console application displayed on a GUI.  He asked how to have data generated by a GUI application displayed in a console.